# How can I shrink/use a Logical Volume and use it as swap

Tags: disk, resize2fs, proxmox

How am I able to reduce /var/lib/vz logical volume (/dev/vg/data) and use it/increase the current swap size?

/etc/fstab

```
UUID=c4408a1c-aa5b-4ce2-a9e8-1673660331e9       /       ext4    defaults        0       1
LABEL=EFI_SYSPART       /boot/efi       vfat    defaults        0       1
UUID=c90b3083-1b43-427c-8016-1d2406c36417       /var/lib/vz     ext4    defaults        0       0
UUID=e585755c-9908-4c01-a89b-d7fb1880b8f8       swap    swap    defaults        0       0
UUID=aea8f278-23a8-4ce0-97ca-4354720ca602       swap    swap    defaults        0       0
```

vgdisplay

```
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               vg
  System ID
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  3
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                1
  Open LV               1
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               386.97 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              99065
  Alloc PE / Size       99065 / 386.97 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0
  VG UUID               e2YzU3-HzQe-DIqH-HGNr-tFqc-cWO1-K92uOR
```

lvdisplay | grep "LV Path|LV Size"

```
  LV Path                /dev/vg/data
  LV Size                386.97 GiB
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

easy: `lvresize` to, say, 350 GB (I'm assuming `df -h /var/lib/vz` gives you something like 340GB; if it's far less, you can of course shrink this way more!):

Since you need to shrink the file system, you first have to unmount it:

```
umount /var/lib/vz
```

Then, resize the logical volume; we can ask the LVM tools to correctly resize the underlying file system:

```
lvresize -L 350G -r /dev/vg/data
          |  |   |  |
new size in  |   |  |
      bytes  |   |  |
             |   |  |
       350GB-/   |  |
                 |  |
 resize the under-  |
 lying  file  sys-  |
 tem automatically  |
                    |
   which LV to resize
```

This of course only works if there's enough free space in /var/lib/vz, such that the ext4 file system can be successfully shrunk.

If there isn't: tough luck! Can't conjure space out of nothing :(

You can now `mount /var/lib/vz`  again.

Afterwards, create swap to eat up all your free space:

```
        lvcreate -l 100%FREE -n swaplv vg
                 |   |        |  |     |
 size in extents-/   |        |  |     |
                     |        |  |     |
 100% of the available        |  |     |
 space  in the  volume        |  |     |
                 group        |  |     |
                              |  |     |
          name of the new LV -/--/     |
                                       |
                volume group in which to
                create  the  new  volume
```

Note of course that instead of `-l 100%FREE` you could of course also specify a size (e.g. `-L 16G`). Note the difference between `-l` and `-L`!

"Format" it as swap device:

```
mkswap /dev/vg/swaplv
```

finally, you want to add that new swap to /etc/fstab:

```
/dev/vg/swaplv       swap    swap    defaults        0       0
```

and enable it right now:

```
swapon -a
```